# Auto logoff when user close notepad .vbs

Tags: vbscript

I need script in vbs whose open Notepad and Logoff computer when user closed the Notepad. 
I have code for open

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

and for logoff

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShutdownWindows
```

but i need compare this.
Thanks for help.

Comment: You renamed the Notepad app to `firefox.exe` and put it in the "Mozilla Firefox" folder? Weird.

Comment: Anyway, why do this with VBScript? Why not just set the desired application as the user's shell using Group Policy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single script, waiting for the end of the notepad (or firefox) process, then shutting down windows, which would look like this:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
'run command reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx
objShell.Run """c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""", 1, True
Set objShell = Nothing
'logoff
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShutdownWindows
```

NB: "oShell.ShutdownWindows" won't force the shutdown but only display the shutdown dialog.